# Using Multiple Ledger Nano's with Parity

Tags: wallets, parity, hardware

I have several Nano's that I would like Parity to recognize. I've just updated the Nano's firmware to 1.3.1 and the ETH app to 1.0.17 on all 3 of the devices.

The first Nano popped up into Parity as soon as I disabled browser support.  When I plug in Nano#2 and #3 all with the proper settings and firmware, Parity doesn't react at all.

I deleted the Nano #1 account that Parity recognizes, and tried #2 & #3 again. Still not recognizing them. I plug #1 back in, and it is immediately recognized.

Comment: I know this may seem too obvious, but have you tried restarting your computer. I have heard of this working for some.

Comment: Is browser support disabled on all your ledgers? I have multiple ledgers and no issues.